# How can I add an Eclipse Quick Fix for a custom Java marker?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I'd like to report custom problems for Java files to the Problems View of Eclipse and provide Quick Fixes for them.

The standard way to do is to use the extension point `org.eclipse.core.resources.markers` to declare a custom marker and add markers by calling `org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource.createMarker(String)`. Then, one can use the extension point `org.eclipse.ui.ide.markerResolution` to provide a Quick Fix for the custom markers.

The above approach is a language-independent method of creating and resolving resource markers. The downside is that I have to write some boilerplate code to resolve my custom Java problems. Instead, I'd like to be reuse `IQuickFixProcessor`. That is, I'd like to resolve my custom Java markers using the extension point `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.quickFixProcessors`. Using this extension point, I no longer have to parse the Java file in which the marker is found, I don't have to build the bindings and find the AST node covering the marker. If I don't reuse `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.correction.CorrectionMarkerResolutionGenerator` and its dependencies, I'll end up duplicating most of it.

How can I provide Quick Fixes for my custom Java markers using the JDT infrastructure?

**Attempt 1:**

I defined my custom marker as follows:

```
<extension
  id="custom.marker"
  name="Custom Java Problem"
  point="org.eclipse.core.resources.markers">
    <super type="org.eclipse.jdt.core.problem"/>
    <super type="org.eclipse.core.resources.problemmarker"/>
    <super type="org.eclipse.core.resources.textmarker"/>
    <persistent value="true"/>
</extension>
```

Then, I added instances of the above marker by invoking method `IResource.createMarker("custom.marker")`.

Next, I defined a custom Quick Fix processor.

```
<extension
  point="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.quickFixProcessors">
  <quickFixProcessor
    class="quickfixes.CustomQuickFixProcessor"
    id="quickfixes.quickFixProcessor">
  </quickFixProcessor>
</extension>
```

My custom markers show up in the Problems View of Eclipse, but when I right-click on a custom problem, the Quick Fix menu item is disabled.

**Attempt 2:**

I repalced `IMarker marker = resource.createMarker("custom.marker");` by `IMarker marker = resource.createMarker(IJavaModelMarker.JAVA_MODEL_PROBLEM_MARKER);`. As a result of this change, when I right-click on a custom problem in the Problems View, the Quick Fix menu item becomes available, but, when I select it, a dialog pops up that says there is no fix available for the selected problem. However, I verified that `CustomQuickFixProcessor.hasCorrections(ICompilationUnit, int)` gets called and returns `true`, but, `CustomQuickFixProcessor.getCorrections(IInvocationContext, IProblemLocation[])` doesn't get invoked.

**Attempt 3:**

Attempt 3 is a continuation of Attempt 2. I set the `IJavaModelMarker.ID` of the custom marker as follows:

```
marker.setAttribute(IJavaModelMarker.ID, IProblem.ExternalProblemFixable);
```

Consequently, `CustomQuickFixProcessor.getCorrections` gets called when I hover over my custom marker in the editor or click on the light-build on the left margin of the Java editor. However, when I select the marker in the Problems View, right-click on the marker, and select the Quick Fix menu item, `CustomQuickFixProcessor.getCorrections` doesn't get called and a dialog appears saying that no Quick Fixes are available.

I ran JDT in debug mode to see why it doesn't call `CustomQuickFixProcessor.getCorrections` when I invoke the Quick Fix from the Problems View. It turned out `CorrectionMarkerResolutionGenerator.internalGetResolutions(IMarker)` finds no resolutions because `CorrectionMarkerResolutionGenerator.hasProblem (context.getASTRoot().getProblems(), location)` doesn't find the custom problem in the AST of the compilation unit. I'm not sure how to associate my custom markers with the AST of the compilation unit.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 6):

I got this working, with great help from this post and the debugger. Here is what you have to do:

### Creating the marker

**plugin.xml**

Declare the marker so it extends these three existing markers (I think all are necessary)

```
<extension
       id="mymarker"
       name="My Problem"
       point="org.eclipse.core.resources.markers">
    <super
          type="org.eclipse.jdt.core.problem">
    </super>
    <super
          type="org.eclipse.core.resources.problemmarker">
    </super>
    <super
          type="org.eclipse.core.resources.textmarker">
    </super>
    <persistent
          value="true">
    </persistent>
 </extension>
```

**Java**

When you create the marker it is important that you set the `IJavaModelMarker.ID` field, and I think all the other fields listed here as well.

```
// Must match the "id" attribute from plugin.xml
String MY_MARKER_ID = "com.example.my.plugin.mymarker"
// Must not be -1 or any of the values in org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.IProblem
int MY_JDT_PROBLEM_ID = 1234

// ....
IMarker marker = resource.createMarker(MY_MARKER_ID);
marker.setAttribute(IMarker.SEVERITY, IMarker.SEVERITY_WARNING);
marker.setAttribute(IMarker.MESSAGE, msg);
marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_START, start);
marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_END, end);
marker.setAttribute(IJavaModelMarker.ID, MY_JDT_PROBLEM_ID);
```

### Creating the QuickFixProcessor

**plugin.xml**

First declare it in `plugin.xml`. Be sure your declare the right `id` in `handledMarkerTypes`

```
<extension
      point="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.quickFixProcessors">
   <quickFixProcessor
         class="com.example.my.plugin.ui.MyQuickFixProcessor"
         id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.text.correction.QuickFixProcessor"
         name="My Quick Fix Processor">
      <handledMarkerTypes>
         <markerType
               id="com.example.my.plugin.mymarker">
         </markerType>
      </handledMarkerTypes>
   </quickFixProcessor>
</extension>
```

**Java**

Here is the basic skeleton for the quick fix processor. Note that it is important to check that `locations` actually has contents.

If you make your own marker type (as described above) I *think* you can just hard-code `hasCorrections` to return true. But to be save and to follow the convention check that it matches your jdt problem id.

```
public class MyQuickFixProcessor implements IQuickFixProcessor {

  @Override
  public IJavaCompletionProposal[] getCorrections(IInvocationContext context, IProblemLocation[] locations) throws CoreException {
    if (locations == null || locations.length == 0) {
      // https://bugs.eclipse.org/444120 Eclipse can call this method without
      // any locations, if a quick fix is requested without any problems.
      return null;
    }

    IJavaCompletionProposal[] proposals = ...
    //...
    return proposals;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean hasCorrections(ICompilationUnit unit, int problemId) {
    return problemId == MY_JDT_PROBLEM_ID;
  }
}
```

### Finding a good JDT ID

You need a `MY_JDT_PROBLEM_ID` that is unique! Run the code below, to print all the current ID's defined in `IProblem`. Pick a sizeable range in these numbers, and select you ID in that range.

```
Field[] fields = org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.IProblem.class.getFields();
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
for (Field field : fields) {
  ints.add(field.getInt(null));
}
sort(ints);
for (Integer integer : ints) {
  System.out.printf("%16d %16o %16x%n", integer, integer, integer);
}
```

---

I hope I have remembered everything. Good Luck.

Comment: Does your QuickFix appear if you try to invoke it from `Problems` view? Thanks to your answer I managed to implement my own QuickFix which is accessible from Java Editor, but in the mentioned view this option is disabled and pressing Ctrl+1 doesn't have any impact.

Comment: Nope. I was not aware of that problem. I don't know how to solve it `:(`
If you find a solution, please share it here

Comment: I found out the [problematical spot](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/4.4.2/org.eclipse.ui/ide/3.10.2/org/eclipse/ui/internal/ide/registry/MarkerQuery.java#77). Eclipse uses such queries to find quick fixes for the `Problems` view. The query registry contains queries for defined `markerType`s (extension `org.eclipse.ui.ide.markerResolution`). The referenced check uses the marker type strictly. As we don't directly use `org.eclipse.jdt.core.problem` but extend it, we don't get any resolutions  for this type, hence no quick fixes for the view.

Comment: Also see [documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_ide_markerResolution.html) of the mentioned extension. It says: `the marker type for which this marker resolution generator applies. It does not apply to marker subtypes.` So it seems the only solution for this issue is to use this extension directly instead of `quickFixProcessors`

Comment: Otherwise you could also try to use `IJavaModelMarker.JAVA_MODEL_PROBLEM_MARKER` instead of your own marker type.

Comment: I tried to use `IJavaModelMarker.JAVA_MODEL_PROBLEM_MARKER` instead of own marker type and this didn't work. The reason is that the markers aren't bound as problems to astRoot, and the [lookup for your marker](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/ui/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/text/correction/CorrectionMarkerResolutionGenerator.java#n338) fails. I recommend to use `markerResolution` extension.

Comment: The important point is that you remove `<super type="org.eclipse.jdt.core.problem"/>` from your `plugin.xml`. Otherwise you'll get [`JavaMarkerAnnotation` instead of `MarkerAnnotation`](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/ui/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/javaeditor/CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.java#n521) and this will lead to the [same failing hasProblem-check](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/ui/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/text/java/hover/ProblemHover.java#n221) against astRoot.

Answer (score 0):

Your **Attempt 1** will not work, reason:

JDT UI defines the following extension.

```
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.ide.markerResolution">
      <markerResolutionGenerator
            markerType="org.eclipse.jdt.core.problem"
            class="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.correction.CorrectionMarkerResolutionGenerator">
      </markerResolutionGenerator>
```

i.e. the quick fixes coming from JDT will work only for markerType="org.eclipse.jdt.core.problem".

**Attempt 2** :
Even in JDT UI implementation there are cases, when QuickFixProcessor#hasCorrections(...) returns true but QuickFixProcessor#getCorrections(...) may not return a fix. This is because we always return true or false for a particular marker. However, all instances of a particular marker may not be 'fixable'. Maybe you run into something similar ?

**Attempt 3** :
What all attributes are you setting on the marker?
Since `CorrectionMarkerResolutionGenerator.hasProblem(...)` checks for it, you would need to set at least IMarker.CHAR_START attribute. Have a look at 
`org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.eval.RequestorWrapper.acceptProblem(CategorizedProblem, char[], int)`, this is where markers in JDT Core are created.

Comment: I expect that if `CustomQuickFixProcessor.hasCorrections` returns `true` for a marker, `CustomQuickFixProcessor.getCorrections` gets called for that marker. However, this contract didn't hold in my program.

Comment: While running JDT in debug mode, I realized that JDT looks for annotations and converts them to problem locations (See `CorrectionMarkerResolutionGenerator.findProblemLocation`). However, this method doesn't find any annotations related to my custom markers. Could that be why JDT doesn't call `CustomQuickFixProcessor.getCorrections` on my markers?

Comment: Moreover, method `CorrectionMarkerResolutionGenerator.createFromMarker` expects that the markers have valid values for attribute `IJavaModelMarker.ID`. JDT markers set this attribute, but, my markers don't. Could this be another reason why JDT doesn't invoke `CustomQuickFixProcessor.getCorrections` on my custom markers?

Comment: Yep, you are on the right track. The ID is used to identify the type of Java problem, which is used in QuickFixProcessor. Also, I think if you create markers of type "org.eclipse.jdt.core.problem" and set all the fields the annotations should be created automatically (but I could be wrong on this point).

Comment: I set the ID attribute of the marker. This made `CustomQuickFixProcessor.getCorrections` get invoked in some but not all methods of invoking a Quick Fix. See the description of "Attemp 3" that I added to my question.

Comment: @DeepakAzad do you have any idea why a QuickFix doens't work in `Problems` view? I implemented it in the way described in the accepted answer above.