# Can I configure Eclipse to create void methods for non-existing lambdas (instead of returning Object)?

Tags: java, eclipse

Is this behavior configurable? Couldn't find anything.

Every time I let Eclipse generate a missing lambda method:

[image]

I get this:

[image]

And then have to change it to:

[image]

Comment: These answers will probably help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501648/how-to-change-auto-generated-code-when-creating-new-class-in-eclipse

Comment: Not seeing a corresponding setting, unfortunately.

Comment: This may help but it is involved.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436440/how-can-i-add-an-eclipse-quick-fix-for-a-custom-java-marker